# css three column divs - middle div fixed width - outer divs elastic

Tags: css

Could someone show me how to create three column divs with the middle div 1040px width and the left and right divs are elastic so they contract when the window is resized. this will center the middle div at all times.

Comment: Is your goal just to center the middle div, or are you actually looking to fill the side divs with content, as well?

Comment: at the moment just center the middle div but later on might fill the outer divs with a background

Comment: -1 for misguiding title/question . Do not ask for 3 column layout if what you really one is a solitary column in the middle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can center a fixed width div simply by adding this CSS:

```
div {
    width: 1040px;
    margin: 0px auto;
}
```

If you want to add a background, you would add it to the div's parent element, or the body of the page.

Comment: Incidentally something like this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/fTPjZ/ would be more exactly what KDM described, as unnecessary as it may be.

Answer (score 2):

There is a way, I just find out! :D

HTML:

```
<div id='siteHeadLeft'></div>
<div id='site'>
<div id='siteHeadRight'></div>
```

CSS:

```
#siteHeadRight{
    height:95px;
    float: right;
    margin-right: -500px;
    background-image:url(../IMG/menu_bg.png);
    background-repeat:repeat-x;
    width: 50%;
}

#site{

    float: left;
    width:1000px;

}

#siteHeadRight{
    height:95px;
    float: right;
    margin-right: -500px;
    background-image:url(../IMG/menu_bg.png);
    background-repeat:repeat-x;
    width: 50%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If your goal is simply to center the middle div, simply give it the following CSS properties:

```
width: 1040px;
margin: auto;
position: relative (or static. NOT absolute or fixed);
```

You can set a tiling `background-image` for the `body` element that will cover the area on either side of your `div`.

EDIT: Here's an example that comes pretty close to what you're looking for: http://jsfiddle.net/kqVFy/

Comment: what about the left and right divs do they need position:relative float:left properties

Comment: @KDM Admittedly, there's no PERFECT CSS-only solution for the hybrid fixed/elastic layout you're after, but you can get pretty darn close. Check my edited post for an example.